How to reassign global variable(array) in main() function?
As you see there is a global variable square[10];
char square[10] = {'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

void show_table(){
    std::cout<<"-------------\n| "<< square[1] <<" | "<< square[2] <<" | "<< square[3] <<" | \n-------------\n| "<< square[4] <<" | "<< square[5] <<" | "<< square[6] <<" |\n-------------\n| "<< square[7] <<" | "<< square[8] <<" | "<< square[9] <<" |\n-------------";
}

bool check_win(){
    if (square[1] == square[2] && square[2] == square[3])
        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[4] && square[4] == square[7])
        return 1;
    else if (square[1] == square[5] && square[5] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[2] == square[5] && square[5] == square[8])
        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[6] && square[6] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[3] == square[5] && square[5] == square[7])
        return 1;
    else if (square[4] == square[5] && square[5] == square[6])
        return 1;
    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
        return 1;
    else if (square[7] == square[8] && square[8] == square[9])
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

For a TicTacToe game I need to reassign the array to become 123456789 again, but I don't know how. Here is another part where I need to reassign it but it gives errors again and again. Firstly I tried to change it without a pointer but it did not and I created a pointer but it does not work too.

int main() {
    char *p = (char*) &square;
    std::cout<<p[0];
    char play = 'y', plr, opp_plr;
    while(play == 'y'){
        p = {'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};


p is not an array, this is a pointer. char square[10] should be std::array<char, 10> square; for achieving what you want.

Seems like for (int i=0; i<10; i++) square[i] = (char) ('0'+i); would do the trick pretty well.

Arrays cannot be assigned in C++ (they can be initialised though). If you want to assign an array you have to do it one element at a time. Writing a loop is the simplest way to achieve this.

Somebody please turn their comment into an answer or point out a duplicate.

What on earth is (char*) &square for?  If you learned that from some source, avoid that source.

It is not C++ code it's C code but if it should be C++ code than use std::array and change the pointer things to C++ form.

@Mahdy.n I don't seem to recall std::cout being a part of the C programming language.

Do 90% of the people here have some weird screen font or something? The first element in the array (for whatever bizarre reason) is 'o', not '0'. This doesn't appear to be used at all, and seems to be a place-holder for OP's reluctance to use zero-based indexing. Unless it's meant to represent one of the player pieces.

@bitmask Yes, that part is from C++, but only that part

If you want to be able to reassign all elements of an array as a single operation  (i.e.  array1 = array2) then use std::array not raw C-style arrays (the latter requires an explicit loop to assign every element).   This assumes the two arrays have the same number of elements

@paddy "[The first element in the array] doesn't appear to be used at all," -- It's used in the line std::cout<<p[0]; which makes me think it toggles between 'o' and 'x'.

"I need to reassign the array to become 123456789 again" -- What did you do to make it become something other than that? Did you try leveraging the same technique used to change the values to reset the values?

Start again building a class Square. Build a .clear() method on it. Then when you discover https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square (a neat way of detecting a win), you'll have less refactoring to do. Your check_win function is clumsy, as I'm sure you realise.

Arrays cannot be assigned in C++. They can be initialised though. This code is an initalisation because it gives the array it's initial values
char square[10] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

Incidentally your code appears to have a typo 'o' instead of '0'.
If you want to assign an array you have to do it one element at a time. Writing a loop is the simplest way to achieve this. For example
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    square[i] = i + '0';

Generally speaking in C++ you should prefer to use std::vector or std::array instead of plain arrays. For char arrays you also have the option of std::string. All of these objects can be assigned without any problems. For example
#include <array>

std::array<char, 10> square = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

square = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

or
#include <string>

std::string square = "0123456789";

square = "0123456789";



For a TicTacToe game I need to reassign the array to become 123456789 again, but I don't know how.

One simple way is to assign the elements one by one.
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
char square[10] = { 'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

void show_table() {
    std::cout << "-------------\n| " 
        << square[1] << " | " << square[2] << " | " << square[3] 
        << " | \n-------------\n| " 
        << square[4] << " | " << square[5] << " | " << square[6] 
        << " |\n-------------\n| " 
        << square[7] << " | " << square[8] << " | " << square[9] 
        << " |\n-------------"
        << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    char play = 'y';
    while (play == 'y')
    {
        square[0] = 'o';
        square[1] = '1';
        square[2] = '2';
        square[3] = '3';
        square[4] = '4';
        square[5] = '5';
        square[6] = '6';
        square[7] = '7';
        square[8] = '8';
        square[9] = '9';

        show_table();

        // ...
        square[1] = 'o';
        square[5] = 'o';
        square[9] = 'o';

        show_table();

        std::cout << "Play again? ";
        std::cin >> play;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp

Another possibility is to call a function to initialize the board. Because the square array is "global," you do not have to worry about passing the array to a function. You can just move the initialization statements to a function.
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
char square[10] = { 'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

void initialize_board()
{
    square[0] = 'o';
    square[1] = '1';
    square[2] = '2';
    square[3] = '3';
    square[4] = '4';
    square[5] = '5';
    square[6] = '6';
    square[7] = '7';
    square[8] = '8';
    square[9] = '9';
}

void show_table() {
    std::cout << "-------------\n| " 
        << square[1] << " | " << square[2] << " | " << square[3] 
        << " | \n-------------\n| " 
        << square[4] << " | " << square[5] << " | " << square[6] 
        << " |\n-------------\n| " 
        << square[7] << " | " << square[8] << " | " << square[9] 
        << " |\n-------------"
        << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    char play = 'y';
    while (play == 'y')
    {
        initialize_board();
        show_table();

        // ...

        square[1] = 'o';
        square[5] = 'o';
        square[9] = 'o';

        show_table();

        std::cout << "Play again? ";
        std::cin >> play;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
// end file: main.cpp

This answer attempts to stay within the bounds of what the OP already knows. My assumption is that he is learning about arrays for the first time, so I have not attempted to present more advanced topics, such as std::array, std::vector, or other functions from the Standard Library.
That said, I see there is a wealth of information posted in the other answers here. I hope the OP will investigate some of it.
By the way, if you enter [c++] tic tac toe in the search box, you will find a plethora of other Stack Overflow questions and answers about tic tac toe. It might be useful to see what others have done.

What you want is
  std::iota(std::begin(square),std::end(square),'0');

This will assign '0' to the 0th position, '1' to the 1st position and so forth. Do not confuse std::iota with std::itoa.
Note that I assumed that you actually want the number '0', not the lower case letter 'o' as in your question.
You don't really need to have a global variable for this. It should be local and passed to any function. Or you create a class that has your functions as members:
class Game {
  char square[10];

public:
  void reset() {
    std::iota(std::begin(square),std::end(square),'0');
  }
  Game() {
    reset();
  }

  void show_table() const {
    /*...*/
  }

  bool check_win() {
    /*...*/
  }
};

int main() {
  Game game;
  game.show_table();
}


Here is a short example how much you can buy if you stop using raw C arrays.
#include <array>

int main(void) {
    std::array<char, 10> square = {'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
    // Later 
    square = {'o', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
}

